# How can I join two tables in R where value in one table is variable in other?

Tags: r, join

I have two tables: `gdp` and `country_details` which looks like the following:

`gdp`

```
Countryname    2013       2014      2015
America       $2015         NA      $502
Uganda           NA       $123      $234
Nigeria        $546         NA        NA
```

columns `2013`,`2014` and `2015` gives the `gdp` values of the countries.

`country_details`

```
 Storename                Year
   America                2015
   Nigeria                2014
   Uganda                 2013
   Nigeria                2013
   America                2014
   Uganda                 2015
```

I want to look for `gdp` values of the countries mentioned in `Storename` from the table `gdp` for the years mentioned in `Year` in `country_details` and attach them to table `country_details`.
I know we can join these two tables where `Storename=Countryname` but I don't know how the map values of `Year` column with columns `2013`,`2014` and `2015`.

Comment: You probably have to `stack` or `melt` or `reshape` the `gdp` dataset so that it has 3 columns `Countryname`, `Year`, and `Value`, and then you can merge on `Countryname` and `Year`

Comment: @thelatemail ok. Is there any other way to join these two tables without making any modifications to the table??

Comment: Probably, but it will be a pain to do it regardless. The structure of `gdp` isn't really conducive to joining to other data.

Comment: Try `gdp[cbind(match(country_details$Storename,gdp$Countryname),match(country_details$Year,colnames(gdp)))]`.

Comment: Or, even simpler, `rownames(gdp)<-gdp$Countryname`, followed by `gdp[as.matrix(country_details)]`.

Answer (score 1):

As @thelatemail said, reshaping your gdp data into a more conducive format will make you much painless in the long run. All you need to do is

```
require(reshape2)
gdp.l <- melt(gdp,id.vars = 'Countryname', variable.name = 'Year', value.name = 'GDP')
```

Comment: do we have any special apply function which can take care of such such tables and do the joining?

Comment: @user14353 why did you write xbefore 2013 to create that column?

Comment: I used an x because the dataframe function doesn't like to start a colname with a number. I like Feng's answer. Melt is a very powerful and simple way to reorganize your data set.

Comment: I think not. But if you really don't want to change your original table, you can write it into a function, something like `mergegdp <- function(gdptable, detailtable) {...reshape and merge...} `. It's reusable and still quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
## Input data

gdp<-data.frame(Countryname=c("America","Uganda", "Nigeria"), 
            x2013=c(12,13,14), x2014=c(14,35,20), x2015=c(22,44,55))

country_details<-data.frame(Storename=c("America", "Nigeria", "Uganda", "Nigeria", "America", "Uganda"),
                        Year=c(2015,2014,2013,2013,2014,2015))

# Use the match() function to get all the rows in 
# the same order as the countries in your country_details data frame
# match gives the row number of gdp that matches up with each country
# name in the country_details data frame

# Then we extract those rows using [] and store it to "matches"

matches<-gdp[match(country_details$Storename, gdp$Countryname),]

# We can use cbind to lock these two together

output<-cbind(country_details, matches)

# If you really want just one column for your country and year combination
# you can use this

for (i in 1:nrow(output)){

if (output$Year[i]=="2013"){
  output$YearGDP[i]<-output[i,"x2013"]
}

if (output$Year[i]=="2014"){
  output$YearGDP[i]<-output[i,"x2014"]
}

if (output$Year[i]=="2015"){
    output$YearGDP[i]<-output[i,"x2015"]
}
}
```